# Grab Particular List of Subset

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm practicing Python and I encounter some problem that I'm not familiar with

I have a subset for `array=[1,3,8]` which are:

```
[[], [1], [3], [1, 3], [8], [1, 8], [3, 8], [1, 3, 8]]
```

I wanted to grab only the list of subset that has 2 elements in it such as:

```
[1, 3], [1, 8], [3, 8]
```

What is the correct way to implement this?

I tried to do it like this but it didn't work:

```
for x in range(len(result)):
    for y in range(len(result[x])>1 and len(result[x]) < 3):
        print (y)
```

But instead it only prints `True or False`

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean this ?

```
results = [[], [1], [3], [1, 3], [8], [1, 8], [3, 8], [1, 3, 8]]

for element in results:
    if len(element) == 2:
        print(element)


[1, 3]
[1, 8]
[3, 8]
```

BTW: you can create new list in one line

```
results = [[], [1], [3], [1, 3], [8], [1, 8], [3, 8], [1, 3, 8]]

new_list = [element for element in results if len(element) == 2]

print(new_list)

[[1, 3], [1, 8], [3, 8]]
```

Comment: Yes, thank you. I will accept as the answer after it passes the minimum time.

Answer (score 1):

This will work:

```
lists = [[], [1], [3], [1, 3], [8], [1, 8], [3, 8], [1, 3, 8]]
for i in lists:
    if len(i) == 2:
        print(i)
```

The result:

```
[1, 3]
[1, 8]
[3, 8]
```

If you want to collect the lists that have two elements instead of just printing them, do this:

```
lists = [[], [1], [3], [1, 3], [8], [1, 8], [3, 8], [1, 3, 8]]
two_element_lists = []
for i in lists:
    if len(i) == 2:
        two_element_lists.append(i)
        # If you want to copy the lists instead, 
        # so you can modify them without modifying the original ones:
        # two_element_lists.append(list(i))
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a comprehension for simple list queries:

```
results = [[], [1], [3], [1, 3], [8], [1, 8], [3, 8], [1, 3, 8]]

pairs = [r for r in results if len(r) == 2]
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's just break your input down and have a look:

```
len(result[x]) > 1  and len(result[x]) < 3
len(value)     > 1  and len(value)     < 3

           (2) > 1  and   (2)          < 3
                  = True

                   -OR-

           (3) > 1  and   (3)          < 3
                  = False
```

Your only outputs here are "True" or "False." You are passing the booleans into your range(). Your iterator becomes less functional:

```
for y in range(True)
for y in range(False)
```

Modify your conditionals.

Answer (score 0):

With `filter` built-in method is also doable, though requires converting its generator output to a `list` object:

```
>>> l = [[], [1], [3], [1, 3], [8], [1, 8], [3, 8], [1, 3, 8]]
>>> 
>>> list(filter(lambda sub_l:len(sub_l)==2, l))
[[1, 3], [1, 8], [3, 8]]
```